# vertex in a degeneracy ordering of a undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, terminology

There is a step in [Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm)

for each vertex v in a degeneracy ordering of G:

what is "a degeneracy ordering of G"?  For example what is vertex in a degeneracy ordering  in

this graph

[image]

Comment: This is a site for research-level questions in theoretical computer science.  The answer to your question can be found in a link from the wikilink of your post.

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)

Essentially, a degeneracy ordering is an ordering on the vertices that you get from repeatedly removing a vertex of minimum degree in the remaining subgraph. The degeneracy of the graph is the smallest number d such that every vertex has at most d neighbors that are later than it in the ordering. Among all possible orderings, the degeneracy orderings minimize this number.